# Drupal Gardens Template builder: Can I have this feature on my site

Tags: 7

When you build a new site on Drupal gardens, you can select what features and blocks/regions you want on your new site.

Is there a module, which would let me choose my own set of features each time I create a new site on my own hosting (i.e. separate from Drupal gardens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a proprietary part of their service. The closest you'll get is http://drushmake.me

Answer (score 1):

[Fusion theme + Skinr module](http://drupal.org/node/955878#comment-3637362) will get you part of the way there.  DG may have some customizations that are not available outside of their walled garden.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your reply. But those modules provide a UI for theming. They don't let you select which modules/features/blocks regions  you want to use on your site.